# Angular 6 - MatDialog - EventEmitter - share object to parent component from MatDialog

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, eventemitter

Right now able to communicate between two components. but don't know how to pass user (selected) entered value as Object via event emitter from MatDialog component to the parent component. Here I want to pass selected option value and text area value as object after clicking the submit button.

**dialog.html**

```
          <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedIssue"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
            <mat-option  [value]="option1">Option AA</mat-option>
            <mat-option  [value]="option2">Option BB</mat-option>
            <mat-option  [value]="option3">Option CC</mat-option>
            <mat-option  [value]="option4">Option DD</mat-option>
            <mat-option  [value]="option5">Option EE</mat-option>
          </mat-select>


         <div>
            <textarea class="mention-reason" [(ngModel)]="reason" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></textarea>
        </div>

    <button class="cancel" matDialogClose>Cancel</button>      
    <button class="submit" [mat-dialog-close] (click)="submitUserReason()">Submit</button></span>
```

**dialog.ts**

```
onSubmitReason = new EventEmitter();
    submitUserReason(): void {
        this.onSubmitReason.emit('hello');
    }

    onConfirmClick(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close(true);     
    }
```

**parent.ts**

```
callSupport() {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(customerSupportComponent);
        const subscribeDialog = dialogRef.componentInstance.onSubmitReason.subscribe((data) => {
          console.log('dialog data', data);
          //i can see 'hello' from MatDialog
        });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {      
      subscribeDialog.unsubscribe();
    });
```

Thanks so much whoever helping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your dialog.ts you want to pass your selected option instead of just a string. Something like:

```
submitUserReason(): void {
   this.onSubmitReason.emit(selectedIssue);
}
```

You can emit whatever you want (depending on how you've typed things) so if you'd like to pass more data you could also pass an object:

```
submitUserReason(): void {
   let data = { issue : selectedIssue, reason: userReason};
   this.onSubmitReason.emit(data);
}
```

Comment: but want to send selectedIssue and textarea value as single object like

`userValue{
option: userSelectedOption,
reason:userReason
}`

Comment: Edited my answer above.

Comment: you guys are fast. just found the solution. but anyways thanks for your time and effort. i just did same as you mentioned

Answer (score 12):

I assume there are two buttons. 1) submit 2) close

So, If you want selected data in parent component on submit button click then,

```
submitUserReason(): void {
   this.dialogRef.close({ option: userSelectedOption, reason:userReason });
}
```

And in parent component,

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
console.log(result);
});
```